# JSON.deserializeUntyped returns "unrecognized token: 'NULL'", when JSON token has a null value

Tags: apex, webservices, json, deserialize

We're creating our JSON responses to my salesforce callouts in house, so I'm guessing the issue has to do with how we're representing NULL in the JSON response. Here's a snippet of the response SF gets:

```
{"recordCount":5559,"records":[{"LaunchCount":"1","Country":NULL,"AccountSalesforceID":"0018000000anaaK","YearStart":"2014"}
```

Note the **NULL** value for Country, which isn't a string because it isn't in quotes. That seemed to be the proper way to do it from what I've seen online, but attempting to map response using JSON.deserializeUntyped got me the 'unrecognized token' error. Replacing null with any string, including "null", fixes the error.

So is my issue with not correctly representing NULL in my JSON, or is this an issue with the salesforce deserialize method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In JavaScript/JSON `null` is defined but `NULL` isn't. Try `null`. (Which is different from `"null"` or `'null'` which are strings.)

I just checked and Apex's `JSON.deserializeUntyped` throws `System.JSONException: Unrecognized token 'NULL'` for `NULL` but works with `null` i.e. it is (not to surprisingly) consistent with JavaScript/JSON.

Comment: JSON, like JavaScript, is indeed case sensitive.